# Can I filtering log message before out to console

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I use Library that use *log4j* for logging (in *Spring-Boot*).

I want when log message is contains some string then save that message at the file before console out. Maybe I can do it before using `log.debug(message)`, but I can't modify the library code.

How can I do it?

Comment: Could be a case for AspectJ ...

Comment: This job could also done by log4j2 itself. Use an additional fileappender with a ```RegexFilter```.